# How do I find the rectangular coordinates of the point P(t - pi) using "the symmetries of the circle"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I looked up the solution for a similar problem, but the solution didn't make sense. The book says "If $P(t) = (a,b)$, then $P(t + \frac \pi2) = (-b, a)$ or...$(b, -a)$" but doesn't say why.

Answer (score 1):

Take the entire circle and rotate it clockwise by $\pi$ radians. Now P has shifted to a new location. It is now on the other side of the x- and y- axes, but the distances along either axes to the center of the circle remain unchanged.

The new coordinates - and thus, the answer -, then, are $(\frac {-4}5,\frac 35)$.